# condition do mark a pixel in an image

Tags: matlab, if-statement, pixel

I have an image and I've selected 10 pixels that I want put a marker on them

```
rasterpoints = xlsread('coordinates_sat3.xlsx'); %# 10 pair of coordinates of pixels on my image  

diff_win_spr %# 10x1 vector with positive and negative values
```

now I want differ the kind of marker to insert in my image depending the cellvalue in diff_win_spr be positive or negative

```
marker1 = 'o';
marker2 = '+';

for ii=1:10
    if diff_win_spr(ii)<0;
        for ii=1:10;
        rastermarkers=insertMarker(a,rasterpoints(ii,:),marker1,'size', 10);%%% if diff_win_spr is negative I want marker1 in the rasterpoint position on the image a
        end
    else diff_win_spr(ii)>0;
        for ii=1:10;
        rastermarkers=insertMarker(a,rasterpoints(ii,:),marker2,'size', 10);%%% if diff_win_spr is positive I want marker2 in the rasterpoint position on the image a
        end
    end
end
```

my output image only show me the 10th marker (with the right symbol bytheway)

```
c=imshow(rastermarkers)
%imwrite(b,'sat_mark.tif','WriteMode','append');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite `rastermarkers` on each iteration, using the same unmodified images as an Input. Change your code to:

```
marker1 = 'o';
marker2 = '+';

for ii=1:10
    if diff_win_spr(ii)<0;
        a=insertMarker(a,rasterpoints(ii,:),marker1,'size', 10);
    else diff_win_spr(ii)>0;
        a=insertMarker(a,rasterpoints(ii,:),marker2,'size', 10);
    end
end
```

Your output is now `a`

Comment: thanks...it was an inprovement, but now my output image has 10 marker1 overwrited by 10 marker2. do you suspect why?
it look like the if condition is not working.

Comment: @rochinha44: I saw the first error and did not finish reading your code, assuming there is only one. You have two nested loops, both using the same iterator `ii`. That can't be right. I'll update my answer.